# Django - modelform + model property

Tags: django, database, properties, modelform

I am trying to solve one issue about saving data in db.

This is an example how I think of it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fieldX = models.SomeFieldType()

    @property:
    def foo(self):
       return self._foo
    
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, var):
       self._foo=var

    



class MyModelForm(models.Modelform):
   class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

The thing is I have dict that I am passing to this form (so I am not using view or any provided interaction with user directly. In dict I have some fields and what I want to do is one field that is passed to use it as model property but I do not want it to be saved in db.

So I tried something like:

```
form = MyModelForm(data_dict)
if form.is_valid():
   form.foo = data_dict['data_for_property_not_db']
   form.save()
```

Form does not know that my model has this property.
So basiclly what I want is to write some parts of my data_dict normaly to form and db as always ->works fine

and then I want some data_info pass to that property and use it somewhere in save() as needed without saving it to db itself.

Can you help me with this?